# Unable to instantiate activity error while running the application

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am getting the unable to instantiate activity error while running the application, I am declaring all the classes in manifest file then also it will throw an error can you please help me to solve this problem below is my class and manifest file code.

**WelcomeActivity.java**

```
public class WelcomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyViewPagerAdapter myViewPagerAdapter;
    private LinearLayout dotsLayout;
    private TextView[] dots;
    private int[] layouts;
    private Button btnSkip, btnNext;
    private PrefManager prefManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Checking for first time launch - before calling setContentView()
        prefManager = new PrefManager(this);
        if (!prefManager.isFirstTimeLaunch()) {
            launchHomeScreen();
            finish();
        }

        // Making notification bar transparent
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        dotsLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layoutDots);
        btnSkip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_skip);
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_next);


        // layouts of all welcome sliders
        // add few more layouts if you want
        layouts = new int[]{
                R.layout.welcome_slide1,
                R.layout.welcome_slide2,
                R.layout.welcome_slide3,
                R.layout.welcome_slide4};

        // adding bottom dots
        addBottomDots(0);

        // making notification bar transparent
        changeStatusBarColor();

        myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
        viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(viewPagerPageChangeListener);

        btnSkip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                launchHomeScreen();
            }
        });

        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // checking for last page
                // if last page home screen will be launched
                int current = getItem(+1);
                if (current < layouts.length) {
                    // move to next screen
                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(current);
                } else {
                    launchHomeScreen();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void addBottomDots(int currentPage) {
        dots = new TextView[layouts.length];

        int[] colorsActive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_active);
        int[] colorsInactive = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.array_dot_inactive);

        dotsLayout.removeAllViews();
        for (int i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i] = new TextView(this);
            dots[i].setText(Html.fromHtml("&#8226;"));
            dots[i].setTextSize(35);
            dots[i].setTextColor(colorsInactive[currentPage]);
            dotsLayout.addView(dots[i]);
        }

        if (dots.length > 0)
            dots[currentPage].setTextColor(colorsActive[currentPage]);
    }

    private int getItem(int i) {
        return viewPager.getCurrentItem() + i;
    }

    private void launchHomeScreen() {
        prefManager.setFirstTimeLaunch(false);
        startActivity(new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, SplashActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    //  viewpager change listener
    ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener viewPagerPageChangeListener = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            addBottomDots(position);

            // changing the next button text 'NEXT' / 'GOT IT'
            if (position == layouts.length - 1) {
                // last page. make button text to GOT IT
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.start));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                // still pages are left
                btnNext.setText(getString(R.string.next));
                btnSkip.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {

        }
    };

    /**
     * Making notification bar transparent
     */
    private void changeStatusBarColor() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    /**
     * View pager adapter
     */
    public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public MyViewPagerAdapter() {
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            View view = layoutInflater.inflate(layouts[position], container, false);
            container.addView(view);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return layouts.length;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {
            return view == obj;
        }


        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            View view = (View) object;
            container.removeView(view);
        }
    }
}
```

**manifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.slider.intro.introslider">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
            </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SplashActivity" android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.slider.intro.introslider/com.slider.intro.introslider.WelcomeActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.slider.intro.introslider.WelcomeActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.slider.intro.introslider-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.slider.intro.introslider-1/lib/arm64, /vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

Comment: Please show package name of Activity WelcomeActivity

Comment: WelcomeActivity calss present in "com.slider.intro.introslider" package

Answer (score 0):

This error shows that the activity your are defining in Manifest is not present on the path defined. Make use your "WelcomeActivity" class exists in "com.slider.intro.introslider" package.

To check this go into "WelcomeActivity" class as see the first line of code is exactly the same as given below:

```
package com.slider.intro.introslider.WelcomeActivity;
```

If not then you have to move your "WelcomeActivity" class into the "com.slider.intro.introslider" package.

Comment: This will also not work, When I am writting the above package name in class, then it will throw an error.

Comment: You didn't understand correctly. You just didn't have to write this line in your class, you have to copy "WelcomeActivity" class into you "com.slider.intro.introslider" package.

Comment: Open your code folder in File Explorer, find your class "WelcomeActivity" and cut it from there and then find the folder named "introslider" and paste the class your cut earlier in this folder.

Comment: If that still confuses you then give me your code I'll fix it for you.